# How to select every Id in a table where Id > 118 and insert it with a constant into another Table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Table A has Id_1, Id_2 
Table B has Id, ..., ..., ...,

How can I grab every Id > 118 from Table B and insert each Id as a row (999, Id) into Table A?

So the results would look like,

```
 Insert into Table A (Id_1, Id_2)
 VALUES (999, 118), (999, 119), (999, 120), .....
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the results of a select for the insert statement, something like the below.

```
INSERT INTO TableA (Id_1, Id_2)
SELECT 999, Id
FROM TableB
WHERE Id > 118
```